# VueJS - wait for updated() in parent before rendering child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

I thought I had this cracked. I'm trying to grab an id from a URL query, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/car?rec140ttKVWJCDr8v`, assign it to a local variable and compare it against ids in a store object to pluck the matching node and send that to the Child component as a prop. It's simply never gets to the child unless I trigger a webpack re-render in the child itself. It needs to get there on page refresh.

I thought it might be a re-rendering issue so I tried random child component keys but that didn't work. I also tried using a computed prop, but had the same issue. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Here's the rendering order in the console. The very last parent update is when the carsObject becomes available, but the child has already been created and mounted twice before then. I'm not sure why.

```
PARENT: created()= [__ob__: Observer]
CHILD: created()= {}
CHILD: mounted()= {}
PARENT: mounted()= [__ob__: Observer]
PARENT: updated()= [__ob__: Observer]
CHILD: created()= {}
CHILD: mounted()= {}
PARENT: updated()= [__ob__: Observer]
PARENT: updated()= (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer] //here is when I want the child to render.
```

Here's the components:

```
// parent
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    // wait for childData to be ready before rendering
    <Child v-bind:data="childData" :key="carId" /> // random keys doesn't work either
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Child from "@/components/Child";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  computed: mapState(["carsObject"]), // cars object coming from store, available in updated()
  data() {
    return {
      carId: "",
      childData: {}
    };
  },
  updated() {
    this.childData = this.getCurrentChild();
  },
  methods: {
    getCurrentChild() {
      // get car id from URL
      let ref = location.href;
      let carId = ref.substring(ref.indexOf("?") + 1);
      if (this.carsObject) {
        this.carsObject.forEach(car => {
          if (car.car_id === carId) {
            return car;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

// child    
<template>
  <div class="child">
    // do stuff with "data" prop
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you use VueRouter for a client routing like this?

Comment: @Anatoly not sure what you mean. I'm doing some updates on a large, complex Vue app that I didn't design or build. I'm just trying to avoid refactoring much if anything.

Comment: Add a flag, eg `loaded` to your `data` with a default value of `false` and set it to `true` once your _childData_ has loaded. Use it to conditionally render the component, ie `<Child v-if="loaded"...`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCurrentChild` method isn't returning anything; did you mean to use `find` instead of `forEach` (assuming `carsObject` is an array)?

```
getCurrentChild() {
  // get car id from URL
  let ref = location.href;
  let carId = ref.substring(ref.indexOf("?") + 1);
  if (this.carsObject) {
    return this.carsObject.find(car => car.car_id === carId);
  }
}
```

Also I'm not sure why you're doing that in the `updated` hook, it doesn't seem like the correct place. I almost never need to use the `updated` hook.